# Laravel4: issue attaching a file to a mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, sendmail

I made a simple app that after one User is registered, one welcome mail is sent to his address.
And everything works fine.
But when i tried to attach a file to the mail (in this case the logo) the page start to load and.. never finish. And do not send the mail.
Do you know why this can happen?

Here is the Mailer abstract class:

```
<?php
namespace Mailers;
class InvalidContactInfoException extends \Exception {} 

abstract class Mailer {
    public  $to;
    public  $email;
    public  $subject;
    public  $view;
    public  $data;
    public  $options;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        if(!is_object($user))
        {
            throw new InvalidContactInfoException('Please pass a valid user object');
        }

        $this->data = $user->toArray();
        $this->to = $user->username;
        $this->email = $user->email;
    }


    public function deliver()
    {
        $self = $this;
        return \Mail::send($this->view, $this->data, function($message) use($self)
        {
            $message->to($self->email, $self->to)->subject($self->subject);
            if(is_callable($self->option))
            {
                call_user_func($self->option, $message);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the userMailer class:

```
<?php
namespace Mailers;

class UserMailer extends Mailer {

    public function welcomeMail()
    {
        $this->subject = 'Welcome in my website';
        $this->view = 'emails.user.welcome2';

        $this->option = function($message)   // -- HERE IS WHERE I ATTACH THE FILE --
        {
             $message->attach(public_path().'img/logo.gif');
        };

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And i call the Class from inside the PostRegister method, just before saving the user in the database:

```
$mailer = new Mailers\UserMailer($user);

// var_dump($mailer);

$mailer->welcomeMail()->deliver();

$user->save();
```

Comment: `$message->attach()`,from where did you get `attach()` method ??where is it defined??

Comment: I found this in Jeffrey Way tutorial. It should be a SwiftMailer method. I get no error, but it start to load and never finish..

Answer (score 0):

You may find it's because you need `$this->options` not `$this->option`. You'll probably also need a forward slash after your `public_path();` like this:

```
$this->options = function($message)
{
 $message->attach(public_path().'/img/logo.gif');
};
```